# How do i get a default gridgain node in openvz discover other nodes on the same network

Tags: java, gridgain, openvz

Im using proxmox and openvz containers. Im having trouble getting the default gridgain nodes to recognize nodes elsewhere on the network. pinging works without issue.
one of the errors im getting is

```
[29-Apr-2011 21:24:55][WARN ][gridgain-#5%null%][GridDiagnostic] No live network interfaces detected. If IP-multicast discovery is used - make sure to add 127.0.0.1 as a local address.
```

im using venet as the network interface. (ifconfig output)

```
venet0    Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  P-t-P:127.0.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.255
      UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:593703 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:333690 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:286774352 (273.4 MiB)  TX bytes:18272326 (17.4 MiB)

venet0:0  Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
      inet addr:192.168.0.203  P-t-P:192.168.0.203  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.255
      UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
```

running 2 nodes in one openvz container works as expected without issues. I would prefer to use openvz containers rather than full vms.

also using OpenJDK Runtime Environment ver. 1.6.0_18-b18.

Comment: We haven't tested with Open JDK. So, you are more or less on own here unfortunately. Nikita Ivanov.
GridGain Systems.

Comment: Do you know if not having a broadcast address will cause it to fail automaticly?

Answer (score 0):

Try using TCP discovery with a fixed IP address and port list. Have a look at how it is done for loopback address [here](https://github.com/gridgain/gridgain/blob/master/examples/config/spring-cache.xml#L197-L223). Put your actual addresses and ports in the list. Also, specify explicitly your external (non-loopback) IP address in "localHost" property for each of the nodes.